# kubernetes dynamic jenkins slaves with multiple build executors

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, continuous-integration, devops

Is it possible to have dynamic slaves with multiple build execution lanes using [Kubernetes plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin) for Jenkins?

I currently have a jenkins scripted pipeline job that is trying to run a [parallel](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/parallelism-and-distributed-builds-jenkins) instruction with 25 branches and this is hitting a soft limit (Container Cap/Max number of instances) configured in our Kubernetes Jenkins slave cloud.

Currently, each pod that gets created on demand to be a build slave, possesses only one build lane and I wonder if is there a way to spread the workload amongst existing slave pods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to somehow reuse slave pods by Kubernetes plugin.

Kubernetes slaves designed to be a stateless, run only one job and die after. That 's why

But, for example, you can create a Pipeline which will get a list of all branches and run them in parallel inside one job/pod.

But anyway, you need to do it by yourself, Kubernetes plugin has no automation for it.

Comment: It is possible to reuse a slave; you need only set `podIdleTimeout` in the pod template. You have to set is to something lower than the agent keepalive ping, or the ping will keep the pod from _ever_ timing out.

This won't let you do _concurrent_ executors, but it saves overhead on pod spinup. I have a pattern in my pipelines were a pod will get used for just a few seconds to check on the status of a remote activity, and then yield the pod for another job, sleep, acquire a workspace and check again. This lets me deal effectively with quota limits.

Comment: This is not true. If you have a queue of jobs and there are no free executors on Jenkins slave's job will wait. If executor will be available next job from the queue will be running on slave started by the plugin. So slave will be reused. It's just like every normal Jenkins slave.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the deployment or replication set model of the kubernetes framework.
This will automatically scale the pods based on the load and number of replicas required. Moreover, the underlying hardware shall also support the same.
**A Deployment is more powerful and robust than a job/pod of a kubernetes.**